# Showing that for a simple, connected graph with diameter $\geq 3$ it holds that $dm(G) \leq n(G) - 2 \delta(G) +1$

Tags: inequality, graph-theory

Hereby $dm(G)$ denotes the diameter of $G$ and $n(G)$ the number of vertices in the graph.

I am struggling with showing this inequality. I have tried induction over $n(G)$ however I am stuck in the induction step in the case where $dm(G -a)= dm(G)$ and $\delta(G-a) = \delta(G)-1$ for $a$ being the last vertex of a longest path in the graph.

Any help/tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: assuming $dm(G)\ge3$, try to prove $n\ge dm+1+2(\delta-1)$.

Answer: pick a shortest path $P$ with maximum length. $P$ contains $dm+1$ vertices. Now its end vertices $u$ and $v$ each have $\delta-1$  neighbors not in $P$ (or it wouldn't be a shortest path). More, these neighbors are disjoint, as if $x$ is adjacent to both $u$ and $v$, $u-x-v$ is a path of length $2<dm$ which cannot be since $P$ is a shortest $u-v$ path of length $dm$. We have thus found $dm+1+2(\delta-1)$ distinct vertices in the graph, q.e.d..